# Error getting an instance of Rumba+ in VB --AUTOMATION ERROR INVALID SYNTAX

Tags: vba, microfocus

Microfocus placed this as an example to connect to an existing Rumba (Mainframe Emulator) instance, but it is failing at the moment I try to get the object.

```
Sub UseExistingRumbaSession()

    Dim App As RumbaApplicationObject
    Dim Emul As RumbaEmulationSessionObject

    RumbaDescriptors = RunningRumbaObjectDescriptors

    If Len(Join(RumbaDescriptors)) > 0 Then
        Set App = GetObject(RumbaDescriptors(LBound(RumbaDescriptors)))         
        Set Emul = App.GetSession(App.ActiveSessionID)
    End If


End Sub
```

I get the error in this line `GetObject(RumbaDescriptors(LBound(RumbaDescriptors)))`

--RUN-TIME ERROR -2147221020 (800401e4) AUTOMATION ERROR INVALID SYNTAX
I also tried to do this since that is the string it returns:

```
GetObject("objref:TUVPVwEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMAAAAAAAABGgQIAAAAAAAByLuk3Pl6UH86EhdmPD2aaAyAAAPA6//+efWIggTnfNjkAIAAHAFUAUwBNAEkAVwBMAEEAUAAwADUAMAA2ADcANwAAAAcAMQA3ADIALgAyADAALgAyADcALgAyADEAMQAAAAAACQD//wAAHgD//wAAEAD//wAACgD//wAAFgD//wAAHwD//wAADgD//wAAUgD//wAAAAA=:")
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you have a reference added to library that contains `RumbaApplicationObject` you should be able to call `set App = new RumbaApplicationObject`

Comment: @RyanWildry, when I try to create a new Rumba object it works but what I'm trying to do is getting an existing instance of Rumba

Comment: Gotcha. Maybe `GetObject(,"AppName.ObjectType")` form would work instead. Haven't worked with Rumba, but a quick google search it seems like this might work `GetObject(,"MicroFocus.Rumba")`

Comment: @RyanWildry I tried and I'm still getting a syntax error. Thank you

Comment: I just did a search on the error message "RUN TIME ERROR -2147221020 (800401e4)" and I can see lot of reason for this error. See if you can find something in relation to  `RunningRumbaObjectDescriptors`?

Comment: We have tried a bunch of things and nothing seems to work.

Comment: If you edit your question to explain each of the things you've tried with the undesired result you got, it might help narrow down the problem or inspire someone to think of something new. When the community is *not* in the dark on the details, it maximizes the democratization of problem-solving.

Comment: @Thank you for your help, we just has a meeting with Rumba team and they said they have a hot fix for that, so I'm going to delete the question.

Comment: @LorenaPita - It would be better to keep the question and edit it to include that fact (or self-answer!) so that future visitors will be aware that a hotfix exists.

Comment: @LorenaPita - meanwhile, I've upvoted your comment just so it stays above the fold.